# Proper notation for vector divergence

Tags: vector-analysis

$$ \nabla \cdot \vec{A} = \left[\hat{x} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}  + \hat{y}  \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + \hat{z} \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \right]  \cdot\vec{A}$$

This is how I usually write divergence, but I have a doubt on how to evaluate expressions of the form:

$$ \hat{x} \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \cdot \vec{A}$$

It is not directly obvious that we push  'push' the $ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ onto $\vec{A}$ then dot product

$$ \hat{x} \cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \vec{A}$$

To be explicit about my question, I find it a bit difficult that though the dot product comes , we first have to take the derivative and then dot, is there a better notation for divergence? I know the of bracket notation but that requires both the vector and divergence operator to be expressed in same basis eg: cartesian like for example if $A=<A_x,A_y,A_z>$ then:

$$ \nabla \cdot A = < \frac{\partial}{\partial x},  \frac{\partial}{\partial y} , \frac{\partial }{\partial z}> \cdot <A_x,A_y,A_z>$$

The order is clear and there is no doubt  but does there exist a notation which makes it clear how to do opertions when gradient is expressed in one coordinate system and the function in another?